# How to get a Windows Docker Container to auto start on login with Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

Docker Desktop (on Windows) has an option to auto-start at login, which causes the Docker Desktop app to start on login.

Is there a way to set a container to auto-start on login as well?

For example, I am running the `conduktor-console` container, which provides a web interface for managing Kafka brokers.

Currently, I have to manually start this container each time I login. Is there a way to set it to automatically start?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a native docker question, but i would suggest to use the Windows `Task Scheduler`, Combined with a simple powershell script that will run the container.

1. Create a PowerShell script that will `docker run` the container
2. Create a task `Task Scheduler` that will run this script on computer startup.

See [How to Automate PowerShell Scripts with Task Scheduler](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/07/03/how-to-automate-powershell-scripts-with-task-scheduler/).

Comment: This is a native docker question. The answer might be "this can't be done with Docker Desktop" - in which case that's fine and writing a powershell script to do so could be a good solution. (I'm not particularly familiar with it, but it makes sense.) But it is a question about Docker Desktop.

Comment: Okay, I agree with you :) good luck!